# Redux initialize data on refresh delay

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to initialize the user session in App.js by getting the token and executing an API call and storing the user's data inside the reducer.
The problem is that when I want to take the data at first, the user's data is null because it takes some time to update the value and store it in the user's store.
Is an alternative way to do this because when I want to validate things inside routes, the user's data is acquired as null and after some time user's data is stored.

***App.js***

```
function App() {
  const session = useSelector((state) => state.user.user);
  const isAuth = useSelector((state) => state.user.isLoggedIn);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  useEffect(() => {
    async function initializeToken() {
      dispatch(initialState());
      if (token) {
        await axios
          .get(`http://localhost:4500/api/user/current`, {
            headers: {
              token: token,
            },
          })
          .then((res) => {
            dispatch(login(res.data));
          });
      } else {
        dispatch(logout());
        console.log("no token");
      }
    }
    initializeToken();
  }, []);
```

***Reducer***

```
export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    user: null,
    isLoggedIn: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    initialState: (state) => {
      state.user = null;
      state.isLoggedIn = false;
    },
    login: (state, action) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
      state.isLoggedIn = true;
    },
    logout: (state) => {
      state.user = null;
      state.isLoggedIn = false;
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is how useEffect and asynchronous calls work. The standard approach is rendering some progress bar while data loading and render the page once data are dropped into the store. Something like this:

```js
function App() {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function initializeToken() {
      dispatch(initialState());
      let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
      if (token) {
        await axios
          .get(`http://localhost:4500/api/user/current`, {
            headers: {
              token: token,
            },
          })
          .then((res) => {
            dispatch(login(res.data));
          });
      } else {
        dispatch(logout());
        console.log("no token");
      }
    }
    initializeToken();
  }, []);

  return (
    user ?
      // render your page with user data here
    :
      <div>Loading data...</div>
  );
```

And it is better to specify initial state during store creation. That is, you will have only two states: not loaded yet, loaded. In your code you have three: default value of store, initial state (set before loading started), loaded state.